# EE1 to EE2 upgrade, need to post upgrade uninstall module from EE1 how to?

Tags: expressionengine

So I've got a very complex site which I successfully upgraded from EE1 to EE2 after 3 tries. I now installed Zoo flexible Admin to configure the CP for the client and when I do that I get the following error.

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/reeorder_lang.php
```

This language file is for the EE1 module [REEorder](http://dvt.ee/adt2D6Z) unfortunately documentation no longer exists. I also do not want to revert back and go through upgrading again with structure, multiple ngnen file fields and matrices. Would really appreciate some advice on how to remove this from the database via phpmyadmin or other method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look in `exp_modules` and delete the row for `Reeorder`.

Comment: Might want to check `exp_extensions` too.

Comment: would there be any adverse affects if I were to delete exp_reeorder_prefs ?

have already backed up database.

Comment: deleted row for Reeorder as you said and everything is good. Thanks Derek

Answer (score 0):

You could of course, for now, just create that file and put an empty $lang variable in it...it would shut it up while you look for a better solution :)

Shove the following in the file it wants

```
<?php

$lang = array()

;>
```